# Reset password in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to reset password in android app using firebase. I have successfully completed login and register process. But I need to reset password now.

Answer (score 2):

Send a password reset email

You can send a password reset email to a user with the sendPasswordResetEmail method. For example:

```
 FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 String emailAddress = "user@example.com";
 auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please help me with email verification too. first verification link will be sent to the email address and then only data should be added to the database.

Comment: I tried putting this in a function .. public void resetPass() and then call this function in the onClickListener for the reset password button but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In below code, I have get email address from user and button's click event request is sent on provided email address. Until task is not completed progress bar is displayed.

```
public class ResetPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextEmail; //to get email address
ProgressBar progressBar;    //show progress bar
Button buttonForgotPassword;    //button for click
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
String email;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);
    bindView();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    /*      click event of button
    * */
    buttonForgotPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();

            /*  check if email address is blank
            * */
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                editTextEmail.setError("Fill Email");       //if blank display error
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   //set visibility

            /*
            *       send request for reset password
            * */
            firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "Successfully send you response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "Failed to Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

/*      UDF
* */
private void bindView() {
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_reset_password_edit_text);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.activity_reset_progressBar);
    buttonForgotPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_reset_password_forgot_password_button);
}
```

}